# jQuery AutoComplete - Result shows encoded characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using the following code to search an ajax file for a query with the autocomplete plugin:

```
$("input.search_bar").autocomplete("/autocomplete/", {
    scrollHeight: 300,
    minChars: 3
});
```

The search results are HTML encoded names like:

Bob's Store (really `Bob%39s Store`)
Bill's Shop (really `Bill%39s Shop`)
etc...

The autocomplete dropdown shows the correct HTML like so:

Bob's Store
Bill's Shop

But when I select one of the results and the result moves into the input field, the input field displays the escaped value like so:

`Bob%39s Store`

How do I use the jQuery Autocomplete plugin to format the result to show the unescaped value when a result is chosen?

I've tried the following plugin function without any luck:

```
$("input.search_bar").autocomplete("/autocomplete/", {
    scrollHeight: 300,
    minChars: 3,
    formatResult: function(row) {
      return unescape(row);
    }
});
```

Comment: you could use a bit of php with preg_replace()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code,

```
$("input.search_bar").autocomplete("/autocomplete/", {
    scrollHeight: 300,
    minChars: 3,
    formatResult: function(row) {
      return $('<div/>').html(row).html();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  The source for the JSON output was a JSP file.

The JSON usage example showed using single quotes to delimit the suggesion entries which I changed to double quotes.

It still didn't work until I changed from using a <c:out value="...."> tag to simply using ${....}.  That fixed the problem.  The <c:out> tag was automatically escaping the output.

If you are not using Java, make sure the function that you are using to generate your JSON does not automatically encode/escape values.  I didn't notice this until I hit a person's name with a single quote in it.

Answer (score 0):

try [`decodeURI()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp):

```
$("input.search_bar").autocomplete("/autocomplete/", {
    scrollHeight: 300,
    minChars: 3,
    formatResult: function(row) {
      return decodeURI(row);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you dig into the autocomplete code to see what function they are using to escape the variables? If it is a standard function then it should have an opposite, if not then it looks like you get to create one :). It looks like unicode or ascii (39=apostrophe)