# Process ASCII codes present in string

Tags: javascript

Ok. This may be a dumb question but I am stuck.

In my javascript, I have a string variable that contains `&#x27;` which stands for single quote. e.g. `some_text_&#x27;_some_text`
Now, I want to replace this with the actual single quote like `some_text_'_some_text`.

Obvious way would be using `str.replace(/&#x27;/g,"'")` but the problem is I write this javascript code into a third party software that replaces `&#x27;` by `'` when I save the script. So, if I open script again, it shows `str.replace(/'/g,"'")`. So when the script runs, it does not do replace operation correctly.

One would ask why do I need this replace to work?
The reason is that this variable is passed on to build a SQL query and I don't want `&#x27;` in my query. I want it to be `'` instead which I can escape in SQL.

**EDIT**
So, I realized the reason for this behavior and potential answerers may want to take this into account. The software I work with stores all its files as XML including javascript code I write. So, it converts all special characters to HTML codes while saving and parses them back when it reads it. That's the reason `&#x27;` gets converted to `'`.

Comment: You need to decode your html entities. Take a look at this answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode

Comment: Also - you can do it easier on most server side scripting. i.e with PHP you can use `htmlspecialchars_decode` and then escape it.

Comment: `str.replace(/&amp;#x27;/g,"'")`?

Comment: And if @Bergi’s suggestion doesn’t help, try to trick the software by something like `str.replace(new RegExp("&"+"#"+"x27;", "g"), "'")` … try recognizing _that_ as numeric character reference, you sneaky little 3rd party party-crasher software!

Comment: @Bergi: For some reason, it didn't work. You may want to post it as answer in case someone has same problem in future and your answer works for him/her. And thanks for the help.

Comment: @CBroe: This worked. Can you post it as answer so that I can mark it accepted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If @Bergi’s suggestion doesn’t help, try to trick the software by something like

```
str.replace(new RegExp("&"+"#"+"x27;", "g"), "'")
```

– basically splitting the numeric character reference into several pieces, so that the software that is messing with things can’t recognize it as such any more.

Comment: This worked for me. Although for someone else with similar problem, @Bergi 's answer may work as well.

Comment: Still needed this answer for me. For ref, this issue is basically like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482949/jquery-autocomplete-result-shows-encoded-characters  but with the &#x27; apostrophe character from (previously) XML data loading via JSON